# Add Contact in iPhone Address Book iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, ios10

App crash on iOS 10 when I am trying to save my contact in address book, not getting error on less than iOS 10. I also add "Contacts usage description" in info.plist but I am getting this on console and app crashes

```
[MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is/private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
[MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
```

Comment: Did you get authorization to access contacts?

Comment: Yes, not getting error on <iOS 10. I also add "Contacts usage description" in info.plist but my app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Base on your crash try to `off` **App Group** option:-

[image: Look at this]